# Vertical line in vistime

Tags: r, ggplot2, vistime

I am having problems getting a vertical line to show in my vistime block of code (to represent the current year, 2021).  Stackoverflow has offered up a plotly (via add_segments) and ggplot (via geom_vline) option to achieve this, but while I dont get an error in the code block, the line doesn't materialize in the plot window. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thankyou.

````
library(vistime)
Wand <- read.csv(text="event,group,start,end,color,fontcolor
Mature,Legend,2004-01-01,2009-12-31,#37782C,white
Seedlings,Legend,2010-01-01,2015-12-31,#9FD983,black
Absent,Legend,2016-01-01,2021-12-31,#FEFED3,black
Unknown,Legend,2022-01-01,2027-12-31,#DCDCDC,black
Burn,Legend,2028-01-01,2033-12-31,#000000,white
Extirpated :),Legend,2034-01-01,2039-12-31,#024064,white
,Caravan Park,2004-01-01,2008-12-31,#37782C,black
,Caravan Park,2009-01-01,2010-12-31,#DCDCDC,black
,Caravan Park,2011-01-01,2011-12-31,#37782C,black
,Caravan Park,2012-01-01,2013-12-31,#DCDCDC,black
,Caravan Park,2014-01-01,2014-12-31,#9FD983,black
,Caravan Park,2015-01-01,2018-12-31,#DCDCDC,black
,Caravan Park,2019-01-01,2020-12-31,#9FD983,black
Annual Surveillance,Caravan Park,2021-01-01,2026-12-31,#3CB3C0,black
,Caravan Park,2027-01-01,2027-12-31,#024064,black
,Gravel Pit,2004-01-01,2008-12-31,#37782C,black
,Gravel Pit,2009-01-01,2009-12-31,#DCDCDC,black
,Gravel Pit,2010-01-01,2010-12-31,#37782C,black
,Gravel Pit,2011-01-01,2018-12-31,#DCDCDC,black
,Gravel Pit,2019-01-01,2020-12-31,#37782C,black
Annual Surveillance,Gravel Pit,2021-01-01,2035-12-31,#3CB3C0,black
,Gravel Pit,2036-01-01,2036-12-31,#024064,black")
gg_vistime(Wand,show_labels = TRUE,background_lines = NULL,optimize_y = TRUE, title = "Town", linewidth=20)```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Woops sorry.  That just shows how frustrated I got!  I meant to say add a vertical line for hte current year.  Stefan was able to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a vertical line via `geom_vline` by first converting your desired data to a date time and afterwards to a numeric:

```r
library(vistime)
library(ggplot2)

gg_vistime(Wand,show_labels = TRUE,background_lines = NULL,optimize_y = TRUE, title = "Town", linewidth=20) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01")), color = "red", size = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Stefan, that solved the problem perfectly!  Very thankful.